# Function add class to second menu specific items if the page has a certain category

Tags: categories, menus

I would need to set a class of a secondary menu if the currently loaded page has, for example, the category "clients".

For different primary menus I will use https://en.wordpress.org/plugins/conditional-menus/

and to make the category available on the page, I use functions

I would like to create a similar type of menu as on [partners.cz](https://www.partners.cz/)

Comment: You can easily do this via javascript, PHP solution is also possible but you will need to write code by using custom menu walker class if you can provide your category page link I can check about javascript code.

Comment: Finally I solved it through the plugin [https://wordpress.org/plugins/conditional-menus/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/conditional-menus/).